# How does Figma crop pictures accurately?

Tags: figma

Figma can use drag and drop to crop pictures, but it is difficult to get to the specific size? How to do it?

There is a demo picture to illustrate my problem.

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about programming and is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see changing the width from the input field changes the width of the image, not the crop.

Unfortunately you can only do it with the mouse. I tried pressing SHIFT/ALT/CTRL and all kind of combos, but it does nothing.

You will need a good mouse and patience, if you have lots of images to crop, or you could crop them in a specialized program like gimp or photoshop and then add them to Figma. Figma is not really good for photo manipulation, it's more for layouts and web design.